# File Handling Calculation In C

Tags: c, file, file-handling

I want to calculate body mass index and write it to the file.I've tried to calculate it in a another function as you can see but output is just 0.Then I've tried different functions like int calculate returns to w/h*h but none of them give me the right answers.I couldn't find another way.

```
#include <stdio.h>
struct person
{
    int personId;
    double height;
    double weight;
    double BMI;
}; 

void calculate (double h, double w)
{
    struct person p1;
    p1.BMI = w / h*h ;
}
void write () {
FILE *file;
struct person p1;
file = fopen("bmi.txt","w");
if (file == NULL)
{
    printf("Error");
}
else
{
    printf("Person ID: "); scanf("%d",&p1.personId);
    printf("Height: "); scanf("%lf",&p1.height);
    printf("Weight: "); scanf("%lf",&p1.weight);
    calculate(p1.height,p1.weight);
    fwrite(&p1,sizeof(p1),1,file);

 }
fclose(file);
}

void read() {
FILE *file;
struct person p1;
file = fopen("bmi.txt","r");
if (file == NULL)
{
    printf("Error");
}
else
{
    while (!feof(file))
    {
        fread(&p1,sizeof(p1),1,file);
        printf("Person ID: %d\n",p1.personId);
        printf("Height: %f\n",p1.height);
        printf("Weight: %f\n",p1.weight);
        printf ("BMI: %f\n",p1.BMI);
    }
}
fclose(file);
}

int main () {
write();
read();
}
```

Comment: `h*h` --> `(h*h)`, `void calculate (double h, double w)` --> `void calculate (struct person *p)`

Comment: `while ( !feof)) {...}` again. BTW `read()` and `write()` are terrible names for functions. Just saying...

Comment: You read the input data with `fread`, which reads binary data. Do you get the expected data from the file? (It seems more likely that you want to read text data.)

Comment: Start maing your code compile or provide the actual code which **does** compile. For this enable warnings and clean them up before asking.

Comment: Thanks for the comment.I've read everything before asking and it was seeming right to me.However I will read again and I'm gonna be more careful next time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct person {
    int personId;
    double height;
    double weight;
    double BMI;
}; 

double calculate (double h, double w){//change to return result
    return w / (h*h);//Need parentheses
}

void write_person(void){
    FILE *file;
    struct person p1;

    if ((file = fopen("bmi.dat", "ab")) == NULL){
        perror("fopen in write_person");
    } else {
        printf("Person ID : "); scanf("%d", &p1.personId);
        printf("Height(m) : "); scanf("%lf",&p1.height);
        printf("Weight(kg): "); scanf("%lf",&p1.weight);
        p1.BMI = calculate(p1.height,p1.weight);
        fwrite(&p1, sizeof(p1), 1, file);
        fclose(file);//Should be into else-block
     }
}

void read_person(void){
    FILE *file;
    struct person p1;

    if ((fopen("bmi.dat","rb")) == NULL){
        perror("fopen in read_person");
    } else {
        while (fread(&p1, sizeof(p1), 1, file) > 0){//don't use !feof(file) because EOF occurs at fread So Display of incorrect data.
            printf("Person ID: %d\n", p1.personId);
            printf("Height   : %.3f(m)\n", p1.height);
            printf("Weight   : %.1f(kg)\n", p1.weight);
            printf("BMI      : %.2f\n\n", p1.BMI);
        }
        fclose(file);
    }
}

int main (void) {
    write_person();
    read_person();

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Although you grasp some concepts of your assignment, there are many errors:

1. In `main`, you will generally first want to `read` data before you `write` them.
2. A function that does not return anything is useless: check `calculate`.
3. In `write` you are getting information from `stdin`. You should use the information you read from your input file. Check your function declaration of `write`: shouldn't it take a `person` as its input parameter?
4. Shouldn't `read` return something? For eaxmple the information just read? Use `malloc` to get memory that you can return.

See also the comments of others for more suggestions.